# ITfoxtec and .net6.0 PublishTrimmed produces a NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I use ITfoxtec library in order to authenticate with SAML2.0.
The project targets .Net6.0 and all was working fine until one of my colleagues decided to activate the **PublishTrimmed** tag inside the .csproj file.

Since then, a **NullReferenceException** occurs in the library, here is the stacktrace:

```
SamlController;Login;##ERROR##;Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Cryptography.Saml2SignedText.SignData(Byte[] input)
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2RedirectBinding.SigneQueryString(String queryString, X509Certificate2 signingCertificate)
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2RedirectBinding.BindInternal(Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse, String messageName)
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Binding`1.Bind(Saml2Request saml2Request)
```

My question is very simple: is there a way to get it work, without removing the PublishTrimmed tag ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are some problems using the `PublishTrimmed` tag in relation to XML handeling. Which is probably the cause of the problem.
I do not think you can use the `PublishTrimmed` tag with the library at this time.

If you find a solution, please do not hesitate to share it.

Comment: Thanks @Anders Revsgaard for your quick answer, I was indeed afraid that there was no out-of-the-box solution